# Using aes_string to change color of geom_point from dynamic column

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Here's my initial dataframe.

**data.df**

```
x y z label
2 3 4   1
1 2 3   2
2 4 3   3
```

To make ggplot, this works when there is only 1 column (label) :

```
    g <- ggplot(data.df) + 
       geom_point(data = data.df, aes(x= x, y= y, 
       color = ifelse(( label == 2), "a", "b")+
       scale_colour_manual(values= c("a" = "blue", "b" = "green"))

    return g
```

On clicking a button called "merge", new column gets added dynamically:

```
x y z label label2
2 3 4   1     1
1 2 3   2     2
2 4 3   3     2
```

Now in ggplot I need to access LAST column instead of label column (it could be label2, label3...) and update ggplot.

I tried two ways.

```
  g <- ggplot(data.df) + 
       geom_point(data = data.df, aes(x= x, y= y, 
       color = ifelse(( data.df[, ncol(data.df)] == 2, "a", "b")+
       scale_colour_manual(values= c("a" = "blue", "b" = "green"))


  return g
```

As shown while using data.df[, ncol(data.df)] , I'm getting the error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (40): x, y, colour

I have a feeling aes_string can be used instead of aes:

```
 label <- paste("label", counter , sep="")

 g <- ggplot(data.df) + 
       geom_point(data = data.df, aes_string(x= "x", y= "y", 
       color = ifelse((label == 2), a, b))) +
       scale_colour_manual(values= c("a" = "blue", "b" = "green"))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in ifelse((label == 2), a, b))),  : object a not found
```

Comment: How is this related to python? Also "none of these seem seem to work" is not a proper description of a programming issue.

Comment: You could do this by preprocessing the data to create your dynamic label then use `ggplot`.

Comment: Including reproducible data would make it substantially easier to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @JakeKaupp Thanks! Please check edited question and offer suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is to do your standard evaluation that allows for the dynamic functionality before you go into ggplot2 functions.

The below takes advantage of [Standard evaluation versions of dplyr functions.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) It creates a column in the data frame dynamically called formatCol and bases the colour scale on it.

```
data.df <- data.frame(x = c(2, 1, 2),
                      y = c(3, 2, 4),
                      z = c(4, 3, 3),
                      label = c(1, 2, 3),
                      label2 = c(1, 2, 2))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

formatCol <- names(data.df)[ncol(data.df)]
formula <- interp(~ifelse((label == 2), "a", "b"), label = as.name(formatCol))

plot.df <- data.df %>% mutate_(formatCol = formula)

  g <- ggplot(plot.df, aes(x= x, y= y)) + 
      geom_point( aes(color = formatCol))+
        scale_colour_manual(values= c("a" = "blue", "b" = "green"))

g
```

Comment: I found my error was with scale_colour_manual when testing out this code. This helped me make my code cleaner. Thank you!